# Where are programs that use CUSE (character in user space)?

Tags: linux, fuse

`cusexmp`, the example of CUSE program, works.

Is there real programs that makes use of it?

For example, a thing that just mirrors other character device or thing that allows networked character devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this one:

http://userweb.kernel.org/~tj/ossp/

It emulates OSS (Open Sound System) /dev/dsp e.t.c. device nodes and forwards all operations to pulseaudio. I believe this was (one of) the first applications, if not the motivation, for CUSE.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be interested to use CUSE to make a virtual serial port that connects to an RFC-2217 serial-over-network server. That would be a really good use of CUSE.

See:

- [Any Linux RFC2217 Client for ser2net?](https://sourceforge.net/p/ser2net/discussion/90083/thread/3af80fd7/)
- astrand, maintainer of [cyclades-serial-client](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cyclades-serial/), made a [comment about CUSE and serial-over-network](https://lwn.net/Articles/308445/#CommAnchor309270), but it seems cyclades-serial-client still doesn't use CUSE.

I found [mhuxd — Device Router for microHam Keyers and Linux](http://mhuxd.dj5qv.de/) which uses CUSE to create a virtual serial port.

I also found [utty on GitHub](https://github.com/microcai/utty) which has some CUSE code for a TTY (terminal), although it's not clear to me whether the `ioctl`s for serial port support are functional.

Comment: Did you manage writing your serial driver with cuse ? which best example do you recommend as a start point ? I looked at the links and it seems  complex.

Comment: I haven't, sorry. I don't have a compelling need either at home or at work, and there's not enough time in life to do everything I'd like. I'll most likely do it if I have a work project that would benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

I maintain a Linux kernel-space serial-port-over-network driver, and have been wanting to move it to userspace for 15 years.  I've looked into using ptys, but they only provide support for a subset of the operations that need to be implemented for a serial port.  On several occasions I've proposed extending the Linux pty driver so that it could be used as a way to implement user-space serial port drivers, but have never gotten any response from the maintainers -- so CUSE looks like it might finally provide a way to do what I want. :)

I have found references to people using CUSE from Python, and [`cusepy`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cusepy/) seems to be the most popular way to do it:

There's a [`quantumrandom` package on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quantumrandom) that appears to use it.

And [`osspd` is another OSS emulator](https://github.com/libfuse/osspd) that uses CUSE.

That might be the same as the one mentioned a a few posts up, but I can't tell because that link doesnt work.

Comment: might be just what I was looking for :) Can you please try to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548963/userspace-driver-for-serial-uart-in-linux ?

Comment: Is there any example showing serial driver with cuse ? Thx!